# Unable to render rcharts/nvd3 graph in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts, shinydashboard

I am making a simple application where I want to render my sentiment analysis graph. If I run the code directly through R which I have written in server.R, I can view the graph without any problem. But the problem comes when I want to render the same through R shiny.

My code is:

```
require(rCharts)
a =shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R | NVD3"),

  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "nvd3")
  )
))

require(rCharts)
require(ddply)
b= shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    newData<-read.csv("data.csv")
    finaldata = data.frame()
    finaldata = as.data.frame(newData$Polarity)
    colnames(finaldata)<- "Polarity"
    finaldata$Freq<-1
    finaldata = ddply(finaldata, .(Polarity), summarize, Freq = sum(Freq), Group = "Sentiment Analysis")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Group, data = finaldata, group = 'Polarity', type = 'multiBarChart')
    n1
  })
})
shinyApp(ui=a, server=b)
```

My data.csv look like below image with Polarity as a column:

[image]

Comment: Maybe use `renderChart2` instead of `renderChart`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758583/rcharts-plot-wont-appear-in-shiny-app-using-dimple-js/21807145#21807145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Victorp suggestion, do change to `renderChart2`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)
library(plyr)

Polarity <- c(rep("positive",3),"neutral",rep("positive",4),"negative",rep("positive",10),"neutral")

newData <- as.data.frame(Polarity)


a =shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R | NVD3"),

  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "nvd3")
  )
))

b= shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart2({
    finaldata = data.frame()
    finaldata = as.data.frame(newData$Polarity)
    colnames(finaldata)<- "Polarity"
    finaldata$Freq<-1
    finaldata = ddply(finaldata, .(Polarity), summarize, Freq = sum(Freq), Group = "Sentiment Analysis")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Group, data = finaldata, group = 'Polarity', type = 'multiBarChart')
    n1
  })
})
shinyApp(ui=a, server=b)
```

[image]